# Rails - Unable to create records from csv file on VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csv

I have deployed my rails app on VPS. I have a feature of uploading csv file and creating records based on the file rows. I am using this feature in ActiveAdmin.

On click of the upload button I call the `import_csv` method through Ajax call.

the method is as follows:

```
collection_action :import_csv, method: :post do
    CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
      item = Item.where(code: row["code"]).first || Item.new
      row["status"] = row["status"].downcase if row["status"]
      row["created_by"] = current_user.get_name
      row["modified_by"] = current_user.get_name
      item.attributes = row.to_hash
      item.save!
    end
    render text: { success: "Successfully imported" }.to_json
end
```

So on success I get the alert as `"Successfully imported"` and if there is any error I get the alert of `"Something went wrong."`which is set in the error block of Ajax call.

Now the question is:

I am not able to create records through CSV file for the Item model. My CSV file contains almost 70k rows. I am able to create records up to 7500.
If I put 7501 rows in CSV file I get alert as `"Something went wrong"`.

Also in logs I can't see any error. In fact if there are 7501 rows I even can't see the request hit to the `import_csv` method.

This happens only on VPS. On local in both development and production mode I am able to create all 70k records.

Can any one help with this? How can I track what is actually causing the error?

EDIT:

At a time in the CSV file I can put 7500 rows and create records. Next time again I ca upload a file with 7500 rows and create records successfully.

At one single time, I am not able to put rows more than 7500 in the file to create records.

Comment: Check server logs in `log/production.log`, there should be an exception.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question that I don't see any exception in the logs.
`Also in logs I can't see any error. In fact if there are 7501 rows I even can't see the request hit to the import_csv method.`

Comment: 2 suggestions: 1)Try to wrap the whole `CSV.foreach` including the block in `begin..rescue..end`, catch the exception and print it into logs. 2) Create 7500 items using CSV, then go to rails console and try to manually create one more.

Comment: In the CSV file I can put 7500 rows and create records, next time again I can upload a CSV file with 7500 rows and create records successfully. 
So from console I am able to create records.
At a time in one single file I am not able to put more than 7500 rows to create records.

Comment: What DB are you using on the VPS and local machine?

Comment: And what VPS are you using and how did you install the DB on it?

Comment: I am using Postgres on both local and VPS. And it's a Web-werks' VPS with CentOS. I installed Postgres just as we install it on local. Is this problem due to large CSV data?

Comment: I tried with the begin..rescue..end but as I said even the request hit to the method doesn't appear in the logs. And I get the ajax error alert directly. In the browser console I get  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jeiwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a clue from the error in the browser console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

Nginx was causing this problem. To resolve this I had to set the

`client_max_body_size 10M;`

in the nginx config file as:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  IP-Address;
        location / {
            root   /home/deploy/repos/application-name/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env production;
            client_max_body_size 10M;
        }
    ......
}
```